# Display Column Value in Case When in SQL

Tags: sql, case

need help for below.

### **Table1**

```
+------------+-------------------+----------+
| Shipmnt    |      Costtype     |     cost |
+------------+-------------------+----------+
|22          |      toll         |   100    |
|23          |      parking      |   111    |
|25          |      tax          |   25     |
+------------+-------------------+----------+
```

### **Expected Result**

```
+----------+--------+-----------+-------+
| shipmnt  |  toll  |  parking  |   tax |
+----------+--------+-----------+-------+
| 22       |  100   |     0     |   0   |
| 23       |  0     |     111   |   0   |
| 25       |  0     |     0     |   25  |
+----------+--------+-----------+-------+
```

i m trying to use case when but not able to get column.

Comment: Show your attempts. And ask precisely.

Answer (score 0):

### **QUERY**

```
SELECT shipmnt, 
MAX(IF(costType='toll',cost,0)) AS toll,
MAX(IF(costType='parking',cost,0)) AS parking,
MAX(IF(costType='tax',cost,0)) AS tax
FROM tbl1
GROUP BY shipmnt;
```

### **[FIND FIDDLE HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df3fb/2)**

Comment: Are you aware that this is non-standard SQL and won't work on a standard's compliant DBMS?  (`if` is non-standard and identifiers need to be quoted using double quotes `"`, single quotes `'` are for string literals)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state your DBMS, the following is standard SQL and works on all DBMS I know of.

```
select shipmt,
       sum(case when costtype = 'toll' then cost end) as toll_costs,
       sum(case when costtype = 'parking' then cost end) as parking_costs,
       sum(case when costtype = 'tax' then cost end) as tax_costs
from shipments
group by shipmt;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Select distinct a.shipment,
    ISNULL((Select cost from Table1 where Costtype='troll' and shipmnt=a.shipmnt),0) as troll,
    ISNULL((Select cost from Table1 where Costtype='parking' and shipmnt=a.shipmnt),0) as parking,
    ISNULL((Select cost from Table1 where Costtype='tax' and shipmnt=a.shipmnt),0) as tax 
from Table1 a
```